# What features should I check on my VPS in order to have a secure box?

Tags: 12.10, server, security, vps

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 12.10 server edition, an I connect to it from public/university. I host some web applications on it. I have always been concerned with security issues. What features is needed to be checked in order to have a secure VPS?

Answer (score 1):

Implement the hardening techniques outlined in the [CIS Benchmark](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/benchmarks/) guides for:

1. Apache
2. Debian
3. MySQL - if you are running this in your instance.

I would also run a vulnerability scanner such as Nessus against it to determine any additional security weaknesses that may exist.